# SmartFoxServer Basic user leaveRoom error

Tags: actionscript-3, smartfoxserver

User 1 is opening the application from Flash and user 2 from browser

- User 1 creates room A
- User 2 joins room A
- User 2 exits room A

... and I get this error:

`[ RECEIVED ]: <msg t='sys'><body action='uCount' r='2' u='1'></body></msg>, (len: 60)
[ RECEIVED ]: <msg t='sys'><body action='userGone' r='89'><user id='91' />, (len: 73)
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.handlers::SysHandler/handleUserLeaveRoom()[/Users/Lapo/Documents/Flex Builder 2/SmartFoxClient_AS3/src/it/gotoandplay/smartfoxserver/handlers/SysHandler.as:353]
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.handlers::SysHandler/handleMessage()[/Users/Lapo/Documents/Flex Builder 2/SmartFoxClient_AS3/src/it/gotoandplay/smartfoxserver/handlers/SysHandler.as:84]
    at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver::SmartFoxClient/xmlReceived()[/Users/Lapo/Documents/Flex Builder 2/SmartFoxClient_AS3/src/it/gotoandplay/smartfoxserver/SmartFoxClient.as:327]
    at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver::SmartFoxClient/handleMessage()[/Users/Lapo/Documents/Flex Builder 2/SmartFoxClient_AS3/src/it/gotoandplay/smartfoxserver/SmartFoxClient.as:1418]
    at it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver::SmartFoxClient/handleSocketData()[/Users/Lapo/Documents/Flex Builder 2/SmartFoxClient_AS3/src/it/gotoandplay/smartfoxserver/SmartFoxClient.as:1401]`

- If user 2 creates room A
- User 1 joins room A
- User 2 exits room A

... there is no error when user 2 exits room.

So, I have a button that connects user to server, when user is connected and joined the "lobby" room he can join and create rooms, when 2 players joined, game begins.

I am using SFS Basic with AS3, I don't call getRoomList() anywhere and I need to mention that I have another application similar to this that is working without error (same api, same server, similar function flow).

Tried different solutions, but no help...

I don't understand why I get this error on this application and the other one works fine and why do I get this error only when I create the room and I expect to get an error when any user creates room, not only when user 1 creates the room.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, I'm struggling with this problems for days...

Update:
If I create a 3 players room (game room) and the game is not started and I connect 2 players and then they disconnect everything is fine, but if the game starts and then they disconnect I get this error.

Comment: Do you modify that `SmartFoxClient` yourself? If no, send a bug report where you've got the code. If yes, what's in `handleUserLeaveRoom()` in the referenced file? Maybe there's a double removal of something.

Comment: show the handleUserLeaveRoom() method, also would I be correct to assume you use callbacks instead of events in there?

Comment: It's and event. I didn't edit SmartFoxClient, but here it is the line with the error: public function handleUserLeaveRoom(o:Object):void
  {
   var userId:int = int(o.body.user.@id)
   var roomId:int = int(o.body.@r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and I hope I save someone some time with this answer:

The problem was this line:

```
sfs.getActiveRoom().getUserList().sort(randomize)[0].getName();
```

I was using this code to generate a random user to be the first to play, but actualy it seems that I was changing the user list array (by sorting it) (sfs.getActiveRoom().getUserList()) and when the user was leaving the room. Boom! Error! Null Object!

So, I changed with this:

```
   var userList:Array = new Array();
   userList = userList.concat(sfs.getActiveRoom().getUserList());
   var randomUser = userList.sort(randomize)[0].getName();
```